# How to create circular image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to arranged clients logos in circle as it shows in image, I have tried but
not get perfect circle, There is any template available for this?

[image]

Comment: Where is image? What have you tried?

Comment: Something  like http://jquer.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Pop-Circle.jpg ?

Comment: sorry for that, just sharing the link

Comment: jquer.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Pop-Circle.jpg before i have tried frome like this template but not get the design similar mine

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

To calculate a point on a circle you can use:

```
var x = Math.cos(point) * size;
var y = Math.sin(point) * size;
```

and then it's a matter of either looping in the value like I did below, or just manually calculating the points in the circle and hard coding them in.

```js
function getCircle(offset, size, point, circlesize) {
  var x = Math.cos(point) * size;
  var y = Math.sin(point) * size; 
  var $div = $('<div class="picturediv"></div>');
  var $wrap = $('<div class="wrap"></div>');
  $wrap.css({
    top: offset + 'px',
    left: offset + 'px'
  });
  
  
  $div.css({
    top: (size+x) + 'px',
    left: (size+y) + 'px',
    width: circlesize + 'px',
    height: circlesize + 'px'
  });
  $wrap.append($div);
  $('#wrap').append($wrap)
}

for(var c=0;c<6;c++) {
   getCircle(200, 100,c * 45,50);
}
for(var c=0;c<=10;c++) {
   getCircle(100, 200,c * 25.7, 75);
}
```

```css
.picturediv {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color:black;
   border: 1px solid red;
   border-radius:50%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/AilIzSF.jpg);
   background-position: -219px -193px;;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#wrap {
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: gray;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="picturediv" style="width:120px;height:120px;left:265px;top:265px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try this,